# parsing - operators causing shift/reduce conflict

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, bison

i'am trying to write a basic C parser but i get many shift/reduce conflicts. I've tried many suggestions from other questions but nothing seems to work. I tried to add some precedence based on C language but i keep getting shift/reduces conflicts. What i am missing? Any help would be appreciated !

bison :

```
%union {char* var; char* type} 

%token <type> INT  DOUBLE BOOL CHAR
%token FOR WHILE 
%token IF ELSE PRINTF 
%token BYREF BREAK CONTINUE RETURN DELETE FALSE TRUE NEW NULL VOID
%token NUM 
%token INCLUDE
%token DOT
%token <var> ID 
%nonassoc ELSE
%right '[' ']'
%right    '!'  '-' '+' '?' ':'
%left AND OR 
%right  DELETE
%left  '&' '*'  '/' '%'
%left '<' '>' LE GE EQ NE LT GT
%right MUL_AS DIV_AS ADD_AS MIN_AS MOD_AS INCR DCRS 
%error-verbose


%%


 expr
   : ID
   | TRUE
   | FALSE
   | NULL
   |"(" expr ")"
   | ID "(" expr_list ")"
   | expr "[" expr "]"
   | expr '&' expr
   | expr '*' expr 
   | expr '!' expr
   | expr INCR
   | expr DCRS
   | expr '=' expr                %prec '='
   | expr DIV_AS expr            %prec MOD_AS
   | expr MOD_AS expr
   | expr MUL_AS expr
   | expr ADD_AS expr
   | expr MIN_AS expr
   | expr LE expr
   | expr GE expr
   | expr NE expr
   | expr EQ expr
   | expr GT expr
   | expr LT expr
   | "(" data_type ")" expr
   | expr "?" expr ":" expr
   | NEW data_type
   | NEW data_type "[" expr "]" 
   | DELETE expr

   ;
```

Part of the report: (Almost all shift/reduces conflicts are coming from this part of my code)

```
State 88

   49 expr: expr . "[" expr "]"
   50        | expr . '&' expr
   51        | expr . '*' expr
   52        | expr . '!' expr
   53        | expr . INCR
   54        | expr . DCRS
   55        | expr . '=' expr
   55        | expr '=' expr .  ['!', '&', '*', LE, GE, EQ, NE, LT, GT, MUL_AS, DIV_AS, ADD_AS, MIN_AS, MOD_AS, INCR, DCRS, ";", "[", "]", ")", ')', ';', '=', "?", ":", ',']
   56        | expr . DIV_AS expr
   57        | expr . MOD_AS expr
   58        | expr . MUL_AS expr
   59        | expr . ADD_AS expr
   60        | expr . MIN_AS expr
   61        | expr . LE expr
   62        | expr . GE expr
   63        | expr . NE expr
   64        | expr . EQ expr
   65        | expr . GT expr
   66        | expr . LT expr
   68        | expr . "?" expr ":" expr

    '!'     shift, and go to state 44
    '&'     shift, and go to state 45
    '*'     shift, and go to state 46
    LE      shift, and go to state 47
    GE      shift, and go to state 48
    EQ      shift, and go to state 49
    NE      shift, and go to state 50
    LT      shift, and go to state 51
    GT      shift, and go to state 52
    MUL_AS  shift, and go to state 53
    DIV_AS  shift, and go to state 54
    ADD_AS  shift, and go to state 55
    MIN_AS  shift, and go to state 56
    MOD_AS  shift, and go to state 57
    INCR    shift, and go to state 58
    DCRS    shift, and go to state 59
    "["     shift, and go to state 60
    '='     shift, and go to state 61
    "?"     shift, and go to state 62

    '!'       [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    '&'       [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    '*'       [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    LE        [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    GE        [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    EQ        [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    NE        [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    LT        [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    GT        [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    MUL_AS    [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    DIV_AS    [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    ADD_AS    [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    MIN_AS    [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    MOD_AS    [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    INCR      [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    DCRS      [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    "["       [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    '='       [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    "?"       [reduce using rule 55 (expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 55 (expr)
```

Comment: The alternative `| expr '=' expr        %prec '='` is probably causing most of the trouble.  As a temporary measure, remove that and see how much things change.  I'm not sure how you've organized your operator precedences; I don't see `'='` in the list, so I don't know how Bison is interpreting that precedence.  Is an equals sign also another operator, such as `EQ`?  You have both `'<'` and `LT` as comparator rules — what's the difference?  It may not matter, but it is confusing to an outsider without complete information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use precedence declarations to disambiguate expression parses:

1. You need to declare *every* operator. (In the state whose transitions you cite, the error is the related specifically to <kbd>=</kbd>, whose precedence you have not declared.)
2. You need to list the precedence relations in the correct order, according to the grammar. (For example, `&` does not bind nearly as tightly as `*`.) Also, `+` and `-` are left associative.

Alternatively, you could use the expression syntax in the  C grammar in the C standard as a basis. It is written with explicit precedence -- i.e. without the need for precedence declarations. In either case, it is worthwhile taking the time to understand how the grammar works, both as a description of the language and to drive the parse. Precedence declarations work by forcing the parser to resolve certain ambiguities definitely as shifts or reductions, so they are very similar in practice to the unambiguous grammar which does not use precedence.